# Update svg:line in Javascript d3

Tags: javascript, svg, scale, d3.js, transition

I'm really new to Javascript and d3 and still trying to wrap my head around the syntax.

My visualization contains a line (`svg:line`) and a superimposed, dynamic histogram. The line is currently fixed; the histogram can be updated. I'm trying to figure out the analogous updates for the line and how to access it.

```
function Histogram (...) {
  this.create = function() {
    ...
    this.targetPDF = Array(1,2,3);
    this.vis = d3.select(divID)
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("class", "vis2chart")
      .attr("width", width2)
      .attr("height", height2);
    ...
    that = this;
    this.densityKernel = d3.svg.line()
     .x(function(d,i) { return that.xxTarget(i); })
     .y(function(d) { return that.yy2(d); });
    this.vis.append("svg:path").attr("d", that.densityKernel(that.targetPDF));
  };
  this.reset = function() {
     // Here's where I'd like to update the line, either by exit() or transform()
  };
}
```

None of my syntax has worked, so it's not worth posting it. I've no idea why I find this so difficult.

---

*Edit*: I'm sorry I haven't stripped this down to the bare essentials--that comes partly from not being certain what the bare essentials are. In response to a comment below, I'm pasting code for `yy2` and `xxTarget` below. They're rescaling functions, and I suspect their definitions are not germane to the code for line updates:

```
this.yy2 = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, that.maxDensity + d3.max([plotMargin * that.maxDensity, 0.05])])
    .range([(1 - xmf.xxbMarginFactor) * height2, xmf.xxtMarginFactor * height2]);
this.xxTarget = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, numLineSegments])
    .range([xmf.yylMarginFactor * width2, (1 - xmf.yyrMarginFactor) * width2]);
```

---

*Edit* Here's a stab at some syntax, following [this example](https://gist.github.com/1148374) of animated line graphs in d3. This function is defined within the Histogram class function. **This seems to work, but I'm afraid I'm messing up the scope somehow... suggestions appreciated.**

```
this.redrawDynamically = function() {
  this.vis.selectAll("path")
    .data(hist.targetPDF)
    .attr("d", hist.densityKernel(hist.targetPDF))
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .duration(100)
};
```

The idea is to call `redrawDynamically()` in `reset()`.

Comment: do you really want to write that=this, creating a global variable?

Comment: When settings variable equal to a function, functions need to end in semicolons. `this.create = function() { .... };` or `var f = function() { ... };`

Comment: @jwatts: will correct, sorry. (this is not the problem in the actual code.)

Comment: @tucuxi: probably not. will look into that.

Comment: @jwatts: optional, but recommended (automatic semicolon insertion to the rescue)

Comment: @tucuxi: It has been a while, but in my early JS days I ran into a lot of issues by not putting semicolons in the right place. I don't recommend relying on optional. But noted. Thanks for the info!

Comment: What are xxTarget(i) and yy2(d)?

Comment: @tucuxi: Added definitions. There are obviously variables in there that I haven't defined in the excerpt, but they're defined in the real code. I can get the line to plot just fine, I just can't figure out how to remove or update it.

Comment: if you upload a running example to JSFiddle, i'll try to play with it to see what I can do; you can add external JS files to JSFiddle via the Add Resources option (use http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js); also, including JQuery would make my life easier.